# Rails Unicorn init script not executing. Says Ruby can't be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

Having trouble getting unicorn to run as a service. when I call "sudo service unicorn restart", I get the error below.

If I call '/var/www/mysite/bin/unicorn -D -c /var/www/mysite/config/unicorn.rb -E production' from the app's root directory, it runs just fine. And I can even call "sudo service unicorn restart" after that just fine.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
ubuntu@ip:$ sudo service unicorn restart
Couldn't reload, starting '/var/www/mysite/bin/unicorn -D -c /var/www/mysite/config/unicorn.rb -E production' instead
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

Here's the terminal output to show which ruby the system is using.

```
ubuntu@ip:$ which ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04. Rails 4, Ruby 2.1 and nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your rbenv installation is only loaded for the ubuntu user, but you're running unicorn as root.

You might want to install rbenv for your root user, or install it globally.

Comment: I will try your suggestions. I have the app running on aws ec2 right now and ubuntu is the default user when logging in. Would you recommend installing rbenv to root or running unicorn under the ubuntu user? I'm new to this so any advice is much appreciated! Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Generally, not running things as root is a good thing. I don't know about your setup. If you have a HTTP server running between unicorn and the internet, you can run unicorn as your normal user. If your unicorn is serving your application directly to the web, it needs to listen to port 80, and therefore needs to be run as root.
That's all devops stuff and probably out of scope of Stackoverflow, though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I was using rbenv installed on per user basis.
I used this [init script](https://github.com/railscasts/335-deploying-to-a-vps/blob/master/blog-nginx/config/unicorn_init.sh)

I figured out that since my rbenv installed on per user basis I need to slightly change this:

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
```

with this:

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
```

Hope it will help you!